# Python: read a csv file generated dynamically by an API?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read into pandas the csv generated by this URL:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_DAILY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&apikey=demo&datatype=csv

How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just read it with pd.read_csv

```
import pandas as pd
URL = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_DAILY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&apikey=demo&datatype=csv'

df = pd.read_csv(URL)
```

Results:
[image]